# SSIS OLEDB Connection

Tags: ssis, connection, oledb

I have been working on SSIS from 2 years. I always had this question in my mind and today I am asking this to clarify!

I have been using OLEDB provider for DB2. While creating a new connection, I provide Server name, Initial Catalog and all required field along with my user name. I do not provide any password and it just works like this!! I can give any user name here and I will not face any issues.

Question is, Why is it not asking for a password?

Comment: What is your actual connection string? perhaps it is using windows authentication.

Comment: My Connection Manager is "Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2". I am not using Windows authentication. I have checked th save password option. Weird thing is that, I can provide any valid user id and execute the package without any issues.

Comment: That's not a connection string that's just a driver name. If you are certain you aren't using windows authentication then I'm out of ideas.... unless you post your entire connection string.

Comment: I am sure its not a windows authentication.

Comment: Below is my connection string  Data Source=10.98.32.221;User ID=A156917;Initial Catalog=Rlid1gfe;Provider=DB2OLEDB;Persist Security Info=True;Network Address=10.98.32.221;Package Collection=QGPL;Default Schema=GFED1DTA;Default Qualifier=GFED1DTA;DBMS Platform=DB2/AS400;Process Binary as Character=True;